# How to mock a few functions from C shared library?

Tags: c, mocking

I'm developing an Erlang NIF wrapper over a 3rd party closed source C library. The NIF wrapper is essentially an Erlang module written in C that calls functions from that 3rd party C library. I'd like to mock a few calls from that library in my tests. The library itself has at least 100 functions, but currently I only want to mock 2 or 3. The tests are executed by the `rebar3` tool, so no C testing framework is used. Is there a relatively simple way to do it?

I looked up a few mocking solutions, but they either depended on marking the exported symbols "weak" in the mocked library (that I can't modify), used a full blown testing framework (which I can't use because the API under test is in Erlang) or didn't even compile (I'm developing on Ubuntu Linux). I also tried a naive solution to build a shared library that contains only the mocked function and load that before the 3rd party library (using `LD_PRELOAD`), but didn't work, I got `undefined symbol` error for a symbol that's only in the original library, not in my mock code. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: You could add a layer of wrapper functions between the main code in your Erlang module written in C and the library and modify/mock the wrapper functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most simple, reliable and readable solution is just to add another layer of indirection. Like:

```
// sal - System Abstraction Layer
// sal/stdlib.{c,h}
#if MOCK_INTERFACE
int sal_system(const char *command) {
    return -1;
}
// other functions...
#else
// in the header for full performance
// or use static functions.
#define sal_system system
#endif
```

and then for example use `sal_system()` throughout your code instead of `system()`. If you compile your project with the macro `MOCK_INTERFACE` defined, then the mock interface will be used.

Answer (score 0):

A generic version of the above indirection with granular control per each unit test is described here: https://ricomariani.medium.com/a-very-simple-mocking-strategy-for-straight-c-7e4b357d90e4
(Thanks for publishing this technique @ricomariani!)

Through the usage of the described macros you can direct a function call to a function pointer instead, which can be pointer to a mock implementation in unit tests. Meanwhile it has 0 overhead, if the flag is disabled. So e.g. final release builds aren't impacted in any way.

```c
#ifdef C_MOCKS_ENABLED

#define C_MOCK_DEF(context, api) __typeof(__typeof(api) *) mockptr_##context##api = &api;
#define C_MOCK_REF(context, api) extern __typeof(__typeof(api) *) mockptr_##context##api;
#define C_MOCK_SET(context, api, mockapi) (mockptr_##context##api = &mockapi)
#define C_MOCK_RESET(context, api) (mockptr_##context##api = &api)
#define C_MOCK_USE(context, api) (*mockptr_##context##api)

#else

#define C_MOCK_DEF(context, api)
#define C_MOCK_REF(context, api)
#define C_MOCK_SET(context, api, mockapi)
#define C_MOCK_RESET(context, api)
#define C_MOCK_USE(context, api) api

#endif
```

Example usage (slight adjusted example from the above link):

```
// ---------- subject.h
const char *GetText(void);

// ---------- subject.c
#include "subject.h"

// create function pointer
C_MOCK_DEF(subject, return_something);
// redefine function call to above pointer
#define return_something C_MOCK_USE(subject, return_something)

const char *GetText() {
  return return_something();
}

// ---------- subject_test.c

#include "subject.h"

// extern reference
C_MOCK_REF(subject, return_something);

// mock impl
static const char *mock_return_something() {
  return "test text";
}

void GetText_Test()
{
  // point ptr to mock impl
  C_MOCK_SET(subject, return_something, mock_return_something);

  // run function under test
  const char *txt = GetText();
  assert(strcmp(txt, "test text") == 0);

  // reset ptr
  C_MOCK_RESET(subject, puts);
}
```